# Exercise $26$ from Atiyah-Macdonald Introduction to Commutative Algebra.

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

The following is part of an exercise from Atiyah-Macdonald Introduction to Commutative Algebra.

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the ring of continuous functions on $X$. For each $x \in X$ let $\mathfrak{m}_x$ be the set of all $f \in C(X)$ such that $f(x)= 0$. These are the maximal ideals of $C(X)$. If $\tilde X = \operatorname{Max}(C(X))$ we have defined a mapping $\mu : X \to \tilde X$ with $\mu(x)=\mathfrak{m}_x$. It can be shown that this map is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $\tilde X$.

Now the authors then claim that this enables us to reconstruct $X$ from $C(X)$. I don't really see how this $\mu$ allows us to do that. Could someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X\mapsto C(X)$ defines a map (or functor, to be more precise) from compact Hausdorff spaces to rings. "Reconstructing" $X$ from $C(X)$ means the following: Suppose we only know $C(X)$ as an *abstract* ring. Then, can you recover the space $X$? Equivalently, if $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces such that $C(X)\simeq C(Y)$ as rings. Then are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

The fact that $\mu\colon X\to\widetilde X$ is a homeomorphism means exactly this: if you only know $A=C(X)$, from this you can recover $X$ as $\mathrm{Max}(A)$. In the language of functors, there is a functor $F\colon\mathbf{CompHaus}\to\mathbf{Rings}$ sending $X$ to $C(X)$ and $G\colon\mathbf{Rings}\to\mathbf{Top}$ sending $A$ to $\mathrm{Max}(A)$. Then we know that $G\circ F$ is naturally equivalent to the forgetful functor $\mathrm{CompHaus}\to\mathrm{Top}$. Thus if $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces such that $F(X)\simeq F(Y)$ then $G\circ F(X)\simeq G\circ F(Y)$, i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic topological spaces. Thus, they are isomorphic as objects of $\mathbf{CompHaus}$ (i.e., $F$ is [conservative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor) since the forgetful functor $\mathrm{CompHaus}\to\mathrm{Top}$ is conservative.) I hope this answers your question.